# Excel Number Formatting with International setting issue

Tags: c#, excel, internationalization

I have written a C# application to read the cell value and display into my application. It works fine if the region setting for decimalSeperator is `.` and groupSeperator is `,`, but if the settings of decimalSeperator and groupseperator changes from `.` and `,`, then the value which I am getting is wrong.

In `readValues` below, the cell value to be read is `23.14`. Since the International setting is for a European country its, value is `23,14`. But the value I am getting in `strNumberCell` is `2314`. Why is this?

```
private DataSet _ds = new DataSet();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadExcel();
    ReadValues();
}

private void ReadValues()
{
    //The cell value to be read is 23.14
    //Since the International setting for Europe country its value is 23,14
    //Value i am getting in strNumberCell is 2314
    string strNumberCell = _ds.Tables[1].Rows[1].ItemArray[2].ToString();
}

private void LoadExcel()
{
    try
    {
        // XLSX - Excel 2007, 2010, 2012, 2013
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                                            "Data Source=" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Test.xlsx;" +
                                                            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            // Get all Sheets in Excel File
            System.Data.DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            // Loop through all Sheets to get data
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtSheet.Rows)
            {
                string sheetName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                if (!sheetName.EndsWith("$"))
                    continue;

                // Get all rows from the Sheet
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";

                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                dt.TableName = sheetName;

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                _ds.Tables.Add(dt);


            }

            cmd = null;
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " at LoadExcel function.", "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you set the cell properties of whole tab to general text before copying the value in it ??? that will be the easiest way

Comment: I don't know what the object `ItemArray[2]` is exactly, but why are you using `.ToString()` on it? Maybe you could get a `double` or a `decimal` out if it instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess Excel itself, when you view it in Excel, formats its value to a string with another formatting method than you are getting with default `ToString` without any parameters.

Try throwing in a formatter with `CultureInfo`. Here is an example from [MSDN on ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      String[] cultureNames = { "en-US", "en-GB", "fr-FR",
                                "hr-HR", "ja-JP" };
      Decimal value = 1603.49m;
      foreach (var cultureName in cultureNames) {
         CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
         Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", culture.Name,
                           value.ToString("C2", culture));
      }
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       en-US: $1,603.49
//       en-GB: £1,603.49
//       fr-FR: 1 603,49 €
//       hr-HR: 1.603,49 kn
//       ja-JP: ¥1,603.49
```

I don't know what kind of object the `ItemArray[2]` is exactly, but if you want the culture info of that particular cell, maybe you can get that from there, too.

Comment: Hello Jog,ItemArray gets all the values of excel row in an array, In my case the value in each row with index 2 i am reading.

Comment: I tried with the answers i got till now not able to fix this

Comment: I understand, but what type or class is in the ItemArray?